# How to resolve a character string as a variable

Tags: r

I would like to loop through each of the below variables and print the name of the variable (for example "variable1") but also print the variable value (for example 5) in the log. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
variable1 <- 5
variable2 <- 3
variable3 <- 1

variable_list <- c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3")

for (i in variable_list) {
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: Try `print(c(i,get(i)))`

Comment: I wonder if something like `as.matrix(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "variable\\d+"))))` will work for you (without a loop). Or just `unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "variable\\d+")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do:

```
 for(i in variable_list){
   cat(paste0("\t", sprintf("%s %d \n", i, get(i))))
 }
```

returns:

```
 variable1 5 
 variable2 3 
 variable3 1
```

Comment: wish i could change indent, but need atleast 6 char changes :(

Comment: @phonixor Please check if the indent is okay

Comment: i meant in the for loop :P

Comment: Oh, you meant about indenting the loop, my bad :-) Anyway, if you need indent in print, you can use `paste0("\t"`

Answer (score 1):

i prefer the other guys answer, but more general you can execute strings of R code 
by using a combination of `eval` and `parse`

```
variable1 <- 5
variable2 <- 3
variable3 <- 1

variable_list <- c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3")

for (i in variable_list) {
  print(i)
  print(eval(parse(text=i)))
}
```

returns:

```
[1] "variable1"
[1] 5
[1] "variable2"
[1] 3
[1] "variable3"
[1] 1
```